# Google Maps setZoom() reloads the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm building a map based application, and I have a bunch of markers. When the user clicks on a marker, the map should zoom into the marker and set it as the center. Here is the function I'm using:

```
zoomInto : function(marker,zoom) {
    var pos = marker.getPosition();
    this.map.panTo(pos);
    this.map.setZoom(zoom);
}
```

This works fine, but the problem is that when I click on the marker, Google reloads everything on the map including the markers, thus making it look a bit "shaky".

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

The map needs to be reloaded because you are changing the zoom level and location of the map.

If you ever want to check what events are triggered when you can use and modify this demo:
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/map_events/map_events.html

If you want to improve performance try one of the ways recommended in this article:
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers

HTH